# Filter by class and data attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to find the unique element by the provided variables.

js:

```
var theClass  = "foo"
var theDataId = 2
```

html:

```
<div class="foo" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="bar" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="bar" data-id="2"></div>
```

I know I can do `$( "div" ).filter(theClass)` but how do I further filter the elements to only get the one with given data-id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( "div" ).filter('.'+theClass+'[data-id="'+theDataId+'"]')
```

This will filter to `.foo[data-id="2"]`, meaning elements with class `foo` AND `data-id` of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('div.' + theClass + '[data-id=' + theDataId + ']').css('color', 'red')`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cL2dg92p/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can wrap that up in a single selector:

```
$('.foo[data-id="1"]');
```

This will select all of the elements with the class foo, and the data-id = 1

So:

```
$('.' + theClass + '[data-id="' + theDataId + '"]');
```

Will use your variables.